# how to create a view in Azure data factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, view, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I am creating a new a Azure data factory pipeline. In that I need to to copy one table to Azure Blob and delete the data after copy success. before deleting the data i need to create a view of copied data and compare the data in source database which is going to delete.I need to delete the data from source table only the data in view and source table match.

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Hi i want to know how to create view of a table in ADF

Comment: you can not create a view of the table in ADF. Don't mix up the ADF tables with Database tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know about Azure Data Factory, it doesn't support you create the view, so you can not do that.

Hope this helps.